# Error al mostrar vue.js Vue is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, api, app

> Esto esta en mi archivo App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
  {{ info }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Por favor formula bien la consuta.  Ya que no se entiende el problema

Comment: <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js">
import axios from 'axios'
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      info: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .then(response => (this.info = response))
  }
})
</script>

Comment: me erro con Failed to compile.

./src/App.vue
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

/home/kenyerlingcm/VueCLI/Proyectos/Vue/metereologia/src/App.vue
  12:5  error  'Vue' is not defined  no-undef

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

Comment: no entiendo por que me da error  'Vue' is not defined  me falta alguna importacion, ?

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y arregla la pregunta. Pone todo tu archivo de codigo, luego pone que hiciste y que error aparecio...

Comment: Y te pido por favor que leas el [tour] y tambien [ask]

Comment: Por favor agrega mas código sobre que estas usando, si usas npm o si estas usando algun framework